# Can no longer launch apps after upgrding to android sdk tools 20/platform sdk tools 12

Tags: android, adt

I upgraded my sdk tools and now I can no longer launch apps from Eclipse (I can still install from command line.  When I launch I get an error window and an empty device picker.  Error window says:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I'm not sure what log to look for.

DDMS sees the device ok as well.  I'm not sure whats wrong here and can't find anything on google or SO.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalling and then reinstalling the tools solved the issue.

Comment: But whenever I am updating the ADT, it is asking to update SDK. And after updating all this this error is occuring. If uninstallation is the solution, then how do I update the ADT as well as SDK tools? I uninstall and reinstall this to solve this issue many times. But how do I update all and run the build successfully? Its really required.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue.here is my situation.
i have adt r18 installed.and in eclipse about,i upgrade the adt r18 to r20.this problem comes out.after i upgrade the ddms plugin,it is fixed.

Comment: you should upgrade both 4 plugins.
adt
ddms
traceview
hierarchy viewer

Comment: Better answer is simply mentioned as above. Go to Help->Check For Updates and update the tools as mentioned by user948259. Reinstalling is a time consuming process. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had to reinstall ALL Android Plugins in Eclipse not just the Android Development Tools.
Works now again.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse go to **Help->Check For Updates** and then update Android Tools to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Just update your DDMS to latest version form **Help> Install New Software>already installed> Android DDMS**. 
this solved my problem!