# android Compilation error "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.getName()Ljava/lang/String;"

Tags: android, eclipse

Im getting the following error when i start the debugging my android application in eclipse Juno Service Release 1.

**An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.getName()Ljava/lang/String;**

In the error log it says as follows,

**Message :** Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

**Exception Stack Trace :**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.getName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.DeviceChooserDialog$LabelProvider.getColumnText(DeviceChooserDialog.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableColumnViewerLabelProvider.update(TableColumnViewerLabelProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.createItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$2.run(AbstractTableViewer.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.DeviceChooserDialog.createDialogArea(DeviceChooserDialog.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:760)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.DeviceChooserDialog.createContents(DeviceChooserDialog.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController$2.run(AndroidLaunchController.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

What is the Reason for this? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your Android Plugins in Eclipse.

Check this link, similar problem:
[Can no longer launch apps after upgrding to android sdk tools 20/platform sdk tools 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554300/can-no-longer-launch-apps-after-upgrding-to-android-sdk-tools-20-platform-sdk-to)